# I get an error when I want to drop a table, also it took hours to add a value to the table, any thoughts?

Tags: sql, oracle

Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
> 00054. 00000 -  "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired"
> *Cause:    Interested resource is busy.
> *Action:   Retry if necessary or increase timeout.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that some other session is actively using the table.  Depending on the nature of what session(s) are holding those lock(s) and assuming you're using 12c or later, you might try setting [`ddl_lock_timeout`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-72D43EF8-F7AF-4011-8D64-73ABC4FB2154.htm#REFRN10267) to a non-zero value so that your `drop` statement waits for the lock for a while before failing.  Of course, that's not going to be helpful if the problem is a single long-running transaction that holds the lock.  But it may give you time to analyze the lock graph to see which session(s) are holding the lock(s) your `drop` is waiting on.

As for the inability to add a row, what was the session waiting on at the time?  My guess, consistent with the timing of the `drop` statement, is that there was some other session that had a long-running transaction that was blocking your `insert` statement.  Probably because of a conflict on a unique index or constraint that couldn't be resolved until the other transaction finally ended hours later (I'd guess because the session finally got killed).